# cannot see difference between view bound and upper bound

Tags: scala

In the following example, I am using `view bound` and `upper bound`. The code is exactly the same except for the difference in signs of `<%` and `<:`. What is the difference between `view bound` and `upper bound`?

```
scala> class Person[T <% Ordered[T]](val fn:T, val ln:T) {
     | def greater = if (fn > ln) fn else ln
     | }
defined class Person

scala> val p1 = new Person("manu", "chadha")
p1: Person[String] = Person@31b91435

scala> val p2 = new Person("anita", "chadha")
p2: Person[String] = Person@61e0f9b9

scala> p1.greater
res3: String = manu

scala> p2.greater
res4: String = chadha

scala> class Person2[T <: Ordered[T]](val fn:T, val ln:T) {
     | def greater = if (fn > ln) fn else ln
     | }
defined class Person2

scala> val p3 = new Person("manu", "chadha")
p3: Person[String] = Person@7c50709a

scala> val p4 = new Person("anita", "chadha")
p4: Person[String] = Person@1d686622

scala> p3.greater
res5: String = manu

scala> p4.greater
res6: String = chadha

scala>
```

Comment: View bound has to do with the implicit scope, what's not the case for upper bound.

Comment: Both times you are using `new Person`, never `new Person2`.

Comment: ah! embarrassing mistake! Happy to accept your comment as an answer. Could you make it an answer.